# Prove that if a relation $R$ on $X$ is not symmetric, but transitive, the collection of pseudoequivalence classes does not partition $X$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm trying to work through this problem for the class I'm teaching, but am getting stuck.  I think the key is that there exists some $(x,y)\in R$ such that $(y,x) \notin R$, so $x$ won't be in a partition, but I'm not sure how to combine this with transitivity.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Oops, typo. Pseudoequivalence class. (x,y) /epsilon R then y E [x].

Comment: I think I might have it now with a proof by counterexample. Let $X = \{x,y,z\}$.  Suppose $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$. Then $(y,x) \notin R$ and $(z,x) \notin R$. Also, $(x,x) \notin R$ since R is not symmetric. Therefore, there does not exist an element of X which relates to x and therefore cannot be partitioned.  Please let me know if this is a valid counterexample.

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to prove that for _every_ symmetric-but-not-transitive class, the pseudoequivalence classes fail to partition $X$?

Comment: Yeah. See question #44: http://www.math.washington.edu/~bantieau/201102-061/hw2.pdf for 3.4. Not my link/upload, btw.

Comment: Does your definition of "partition" require that none of the partitions be empty?

Comment: No, but a partition must contain every element of the set.

Comment: Actually yes: your PDF link says that a partition is defined as a collection of _nonempty_ subsets such that bla bla. **Are you sure you're _teaching_ that class?** You also say "$(x,x)\notin R$ since $R$ is not symmetric" which sounds like you're confusing "symmetric" with "reflexive"...

Comment: "Symmetric" means $\forall x,y:xRy\Leftrightarrow yRx$. "Not symmetric" is 
the negation of this, namely $\exists x,y:xRy\not\Leftrightarrow yRx$. That doesn't say anything about $xRx$, as long as there are _some_ $x$ and $y$ somewhere where $xRy$ and $yRx$ have different truth values.

Comment: @Henning: I looked at the OP’s web site, in particular at [this](http://wds-it.com/Home/About); it might affect your decision to delete your answer. (Or not; it’s up to you.)

Comment: @Brian, hmm.. and [this](http://www.umkc.edu/lookup/details.cfm?id=%28%26-%3B5^%408%29W%3DT%20%0A). And the linked SO account is old enough that it's _probably_ not a student purloining the teacher's name. Oh well, then.

Comment: I can send you a copy of the appt if that would help.  Is it not allowed for students to get answers this way?  I told the class they should try this site if they are having problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help, btw.  I realize my mistake with $x R x$ now.  This problem has been eating at me for a few days now.

Comment: @wes: It is allowed for students to ask questions motivated by their homework, but we try to resist the urge to write complete solutions that can be copied and handed in without understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $X$ which is transitive but not symmetric. Because $R$ is not symmetric, there are two elements $x,y\in X$ such that $x\mathrel R y$ but not $y \mathrel R x$.

Now *either* there is a $z\in X$ such that $y\mathrel R z$ or there isn't.

If there *isn't* such a $z$ then $[y]=\varnothing$, which is not allowed in a partition.

Otherwise $z$ does exist. Now either there is a $w\in X$ such that $w \mathrel R x$ or there isn't.

If $w$ doesn't exist, then $x$ is in no pseudoequivalence class.

Otherwise both $w$ and $z$ exist and we have $w\mathrel R x \mathrel R y \mathrel R z $.
Because $R$ is transitive we have $z\in [w]$ and $z\in[y]$. However, $x\in [w]$ but $x\notin [y]$ by our original choice of $x$ and $y$. So $z$ is in two *different* classes, which means that the collection is not a partition.